# how to add relational attributes to gridview yii2?

Tags: php, web, yii, yii2, frameworks

i have a new question yii2.
how to show relational values from other tables in gridview in views/viewname/index and also add a button to that for confirm?

thank you

```html
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel app\models\LaptopSearch */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = 'Laptops';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="laptop-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
    <?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

    <p>
        <?= Html::a('Create Laptop', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </p>
    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            'id',
            'network',
            'technology',
            'sup_id',
            'speaker',
            // 'optical_drive',
            // 'webcam',
            // 'touchpad',
            // 'card_reader',
            // 'ethernet',
            // 'vga',
            // 'hdmi',
            // 'usb3_ports',
            // 'usb2_ports',
            // 'usb_type_c',
            // 'thunderbolt_ports',
            // 'serial_ports',

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
</div>
```

how to add here new attributes and also add a button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for  get the related  values  you can add to your model

a function for the relation

```
public function getYourRelatedModel()
{
    return $this->hasOne(YourRelatedModel::className(), ['id' => 'your_id_fk']);
}
```

and the add  a getter for the field you need

```
public function getYour_field() {
    return $this->yourRelatedModel->your_field;
}
```

and last add to your gridview  the column

```
'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'id',
        'network',
        'technology',
        'sup_id',
        'speaker',
        'your_field',
```

Comment: is there any way to make sortby link for that?

Comment: on top of each columns if click sort them by that attribute clicked.but when it is an attribute of other table it does not have that link.

Comment: @areff   . this could be useful  .. take a look at scenario 2 http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/621/filter-sort-by-calculated-related-fields-in-gridview-yii-2-0/

Answer (score 1):

> how to show relational values from other tables in gridview

Consider order and customer model

In order, model establishes the customer relationship.

```
public function getCustomer()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Customer::className(), ['id' => 'customer_id']);
}
```

Show customer name in order listing page

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            [
              'label' => 'Customer',
              'attribute' => 'customer_id',
              'value' => function($data) {
                   return $data->customer->name;
               },
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
```

> is there any way to make sortby link for that?

Add "attribute" to grid column it resolves the sortable problem

Answer (score 0):

```
        [
            'value'=> 'customer.name',
            'label' => 'Customer Name',
        ],
```

try this for showing name of customer!

if you want to sort this you need to create in searchModel a customerName fake attribute and work with it.